How to temporarily cut traffic to NeptuneAI server hosted on Kubernetes & managed by ArgoCD
Context
I have deployed a NeptuneAI server on EKS and is managed by ArgoCD.
We are planning for NeptuneAI's data migration from our old EKS cluster to a new one.
For this purpose, we want to temporarily cut down the traffic to the NeptuneAI server.
What did I try?
As I don't want to make any changes in the Git repository, I changed the ArgoCD's sync policy to manual.
Then I sclaed down the deployment of neptune-proxy by setting #replicas to 0.
I was still able to access the NeptuneAI server via browser and python code (or CLI)
My question -
There are other deployments as well -

neptune-frontend
neptune-backend

for which I wish to repeart the same procedure but I am not sure if its the safe practice to be performed on a live cluster.

I followed the following steps:

Switch the ArgoCD sync to manual mode.
Edit the deployment neptune-backend to set the #replicas to 0.
Try accessing any project's medatata/runs/artefacts on NeptuneAI server via web browser -> you shall see error.
Try registering metadata using the python script -> you shall receive an error.

This confirms the temporary access block which was necessary to maintain data consistency during and after migration.

Finally, switch the ArgoCD sync to automated mode.
After the neptune-backend POD is up, you shall have access to everything.

